# Mongodb geoNear and group aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have been searching the web for something related to this but cant.

I have this aggreation

```
 Place.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
            },
            "spherical": true,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }},
        { $group:
        {   _id: "$_id",
            name: { '$first': '$name' },
            distance: { $first: "$distance" }
        }
        },
        { $project : {
            name: 1,
            distance: 1,
        }}
    ],
    function(error, places) {
        if (error) return callback(error, null);
        callback(null, places)
    }
);
```

It works, but the geoNear sorting is lost!

But this gives me properly sorted documents:

```
    Place.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
            },
            "spherical": true,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }}
    ],
    function(error, places) {
        if (error) return callback(error, null);
        callback(null, places)
    }
);
```

Any ideas?

To give you an idea of what im trying to do here is the full query im using

```
    Place.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
            },
            "spherical": true,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }},
        {"$unwind": "$participants" } ,
        { $group:
        {   _id: "$_id",
            name: { '$first': '$name' },
            distance: { $first: "$distance" },
            person: { $sum: 1 },
            sumof:{ $sum: "$participants.age"}
        }
        },
        { $project : {
            name: name,
            distance: 1,
            person: 1,
            meanAge:{ $divide: [ "$sumof", "$person" ]}
        }}
    ],
    function(error, places) {
        if (error) return callback(error, null);
        callback(null, places)
    }
);
```

Comment: You are grouping on the primary key "_id" which doesn't really do anything. Why would you do that? Is there something else you are trying to do here?

Comment: The code im showing is simplified, my goal is to get documents with custom fields(using group and project) sorted by geoNear.

Comment: I edited my question, should be clearer what im trying to do now i hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell when you use an operator such as [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) there is no guarantee of the order of results returned. Documents will be processed in the order that proceeded the "input" to the group pipline in order to honour things such as `$first`, but the output does not necessarily come out in the same order that it went in.

Directly from the documentation:

> *$group does not order its output documents.*

In fact your likely to find that the order is by the grouping key but in reverse on most occasions.

If you want to have a specific order of output then use [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and for final "output" that should be your last pipeline stage so nothing else changes that order.

```js
Place.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
            },
            "spherical": true,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$participants" } ,
        { "$group": {   
            "_id": "$_id",
             "name": { "$first": "$name" },
             "distance": { "$first": "$distance" },
             "person": { "$sum": 1 },
             "sumof":{ "$sum": "$participants.age" }
        }},
        { "$project" : {
            "name": 1,
            "distance": 1,
            "person": 1,
            "meanAge": { "$divide": [ "$sumof", "$person" ]}
        }},
        { "$sort": { "distance": 1 } }
    ],
    callback
 );
```